# JS navigating textbox control

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I'm trying to navigate through text boxes nearly identical to excel.  Here is the code I was able to find so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function (e) {
        var input = $(this),
            td = input.closest("td"),
            next;

        switch (e.which) {
            case 37: next = td.prev().find("input"); break;
            case 39: next = td.next().find("input"); break;
            case 38: next = input.closest("tr").prev().find("td:eq(" + td.index() + ")").find("input"); break;
            case 40: next = input.closest("tr").next().find("td:eq(" + td.index() + ")").find("input"); break;

        }

        if (next) {
            next.focus();
        }
    });
});

});//]]>  

</script>
```

The trouble I'm having is that when I press enter with the following line, it moves down two textboxes instead of just 1.

case 40: next = input.closest("tr").next().find("td:eq(" + td.index() + ")").find("input"); break;

In addition, it only works with the right side of the keyboard's enter button.

Code/Source can be found here: 
http://aaronespinosa.com/projects/myExcel.php

Comment: Well this key codes represent arrows, not enter - check http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes .. you can just add case 13: before case 40 if you need enter.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I forgot to include the corrected/added line I had done for enter, but the results are still that it goes down twice.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; a `<form>` cannot be a descendant of any `<table>` element except a `<th>` or `<td>` you could, however, wrap the `<table>` inside of the `<form>`.